# Map JSON to TS Class. If property is an obj and not found in JSON, class should have empty obbj

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am unable to come up with a suitable title to the problem I am facing. So I will try to explain the problem as detailed as possible.

I have a class defined say `Model.ts`

```
export class Model{
    a:ObjA;
    b:ObjB;
    c:ObjC;
    d:string;
    e:boolean;
    constructor(){
        this.a = new ObjA();
        this.b = new ObjB();
        this.c = new ObjC();    
    }
}
```

The sub classes are kept simple for the question
`ObjA.ts`

```
export class ObjA{
    propA:string;
    propB:ObjD;
    constructor(){
        this.propB = new ObjD();
    }
}
```

`ObjB.ts`

```
export class ObjB{
    propA:string;
    propB:number;
}
```

`ObjC.ts`

```
export class ObjC{
    propA:string;
    propB:number;
}
```

Now from a service, I get the following JSON

```
{a:{propA:"some val"},c:{propB:12},d:"blah"}
```

What I want is to be able to assign the JSON to class `Model` so that i get this

```
{a:{propA:"some val",propB:{}},b:{},c:{propB:12},d:"blah"}
```

Using `Object.assign(new Model(),json)` gives me

```
{a:{propA:"some val"},c:{propB:12},d:"blah"}
```

> Note the absense of `b` here. And also `a` is missing `propB`

So my question is, How do I map the json such that if any property, which is an object, is missing in the json, it will just create an empty object? (I am open to using loadash and such utils)

P.S: The use case here is I am writing an Angular2 app in which the properties are entered using a form. If I use elvis operator in html (obj?.prop), because the obj doesn't have that property, the value for that property is never set. If i don't use elvis, then the age old `undefined` is thrown.

Sample form:

```
...
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.a.propA"/>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.a.propB"/>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.b.propA"/>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.b.propB"/>
    .
    .
    .
...
```

Corresponding *.ts component

```
class Component implements OnInit{
  ....
  model:Model = new Model();
  ngOnInit(){
    getData().subscribe(res=>Object.assign(model,res));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `rsjx` library? It provides a `.map` option for mapping JSON returned from backend to frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Object.assign` combined with a default object which you create. You'll end up merging the properties of both objects, with the JSON overriding the defaults:

```
let defaultObj  = { a: "default value a", b: "default value b" };

let json = { a: "json value a" };

let model = Object.assign({}, defaultObj, json);
```

Result:

```
{a: "json value a", b: "default value b"}
```

However, this is only a shallow copy of the properties from `defaultObj` and `json`. Since some of your properties are objects, you may want to deep clone the result of `Object.assign` so you aren't sharing the same object among various bindings in your view.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, libraries like underscore provide functions like `_.merge` which would both merge and deep clone.

Comment: I tried your suggestion using `Object.assign({}, defaultObj, json)`. Did not work. But however, I noticed a keyword `merging the properties of both objects` and that reminded me of _.merge in lodash. Presto! _.merge(new Model(),json) did the trick for me.

Comment: I wonder why it didn't work. Does my simple example work? What happened in your case?

Comment: Yes, your example did work. But it works only at only one level. In my case, I have a deep nested JSON, So I guess I would have to iterate through each level and use .`assign()`

Comment: Right that's why I said to deep clone the result of `Object.assign`, which basically gives the same result as you calling `_.merge`.

Comment: Oh! I missed reading that part. So sorry. Marking your answer as the solution then. Thanks for the help!